# Query get_posts by level depth

Tags: get-posts

I have a page structure like this:

-- Asia

---- **China**

------ Shang Hai

---- **Hong Kong**

-- Africa

-- America

---- **USA**

---- **Canada**

I want to use `get_posts` to get all posts that I marked in bold (level-1 depth).

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to run two queries here

- First query we will be returning all top level pages (*I assume `Asia`, `Africa` and `America` is top level pages*)
- Second query we will get all direct children of the top level pages returned

You can try something like the following:

```
$parent_id_args = [
    'post_parent'    => 0, // Get all top level pages
    'post_type'      => 'page', // Change if this is a hierarchical custom post type
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Get all pages
    'fields'         => 'ids', // Only get ID's
    // Add any additional parameters
];
$parent_ids = get_posts( $parent_id_args );

//Make sure we have pages
if ( $parent_ids ) {
    $args = [
        'post_type'       => 'page', // Change according to correct post type
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_parent__in' => $parent_ids, // Get child pages from these parent
        // Any additional arguments
    ];
    $q = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $q ) {
        foreach ( $q as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post );

            the_title();

        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```